# CodeIgniter 4... documentRoot is not in public... htaccess is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am starting to dabble in CodeIgniter 4. 
Completed a simple app. On local, I have the documentroot setup to be /public/ where as on the product hosting environment, I am unable to set the documentroot to be in /public/.

Instead it is in /root.

So the structure is like so:

```
/root
../admin
../app
../system
../public
../.htaccess
../index.php
```

I've moved the htaccess from the public folder to the root level.

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    RewriteBase /public

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /public/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

and the index.php in root file:

```
<?php

// Valid PHP Version?
$minPHPVersion = '7.2';
if (phpversion() < $minPHPVersion)
{
    die("Your PHP version must be {$minPHPVersion} or higher to run CodeIgniter. Current version: " . phpversion());
}
unset($minPHPVersion);

// Path to the front controller (this file)
define('FCPATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Location of the Paths config file.
// This is the line that might need to be changed, depending on your folder structure.
$pathsPath = FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php';
// ^^^ Change this if you move your application folder

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * BOOTSTRAP THE APPLICATION
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * This process sets up the path constants, loads and registers
 * our autoloader, along with Composer's, loads our constants
 * and fires up an environment-specific bootstrapping.
 */

// Ensure the current directory is pointing to the front controller's directory
chdir(__DIR__);

// Load our paths config file
require $pathsPath;
$paths = new Config\Paths();

// Location of the framework bootstrap file.
$app = require rtrim($paths->systemDirectory, '/ ') . '/bootstrap.php';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * LAUNCH THE APPLICATION
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * Now that everything is setup, it's time to actually fire
 * up the engines and make this app do its thang.
 */
$app->run();
```

In addition, the app config file:

```
<?php namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;

class App extends BaseConfig
{

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Base Site URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
    | WITH a trailing slash:
    |
    |   http://example.com/
    |
    | If this is not set then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol, domain
    | and path to your installation. However, you should always configure this
    | explicitly and never rely on auto-guessing, especially in production
    | environments.
    |
    */
    public $baseURL = 'http://sub.domain.com';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Index File
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
    | something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
    | variable so that it is blank.
    |
    */
    public $indexPage = 'index.php';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | URI PROTOCOL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This item determines which getServer global should be used to retrieve the
    | URI string.  The default setting of 'REQUEST_URI' works for most servers.
    | If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
    |
    | 'REQUEST_URI'    Uses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    | 'QUERY_STRING'   Uses $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
    | 'PATH_INFO'      Uses $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
    |
    | WARNING: If you set this to 'PATH_INFO', URIs will always be URL-decoded!
    */
    public $uriProtocol = 'REQUEST_URI';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The Locale roughly represents the language and location that your visitor
    | is viewing the site from. It affects the language strings and other
    | strings (like currency markers, numbers, etc), that your program
    | should run under for this request.
    |
    */
    public $defaultLocale = 'en';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Negotiate Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If true, the current Request object will automatically determine the
    | language to use based on the value of the Accept-Language header.
    |
    | If false, no automatic detection will be performed.
    |
    */
    public $negotiateLocale = false;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Supported Locales
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If $negotiateLocale is true, this array lists the locales supported
    | by the application in descending order of priority. If no match is
    | found, the first locale will be used.
    |
    */
    public $supportedLocales = ['en'];

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The default timezone that will be used in your application to display
    | dates with the date helper, and can be retrieved through app_timezone()
    |
    */
    public $appTimezone = 'America/New_York';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Character Set
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This determines which character set is used by default in various methods
    | that require a character set to be provided.
    |
    | See http://php.net/htmlspecialchars for a list of supported charsets.
    |
    */
    public $charset = 'UTF-8';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | URI PROTOCOL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If true, this will force every request made to this application to be
    | made via a secure connection (HTTPS). If the incoming request is not
    | secure, the user will be redirected to a secure version of the page
    | and the HTTP Strict Transport Security header will be set.
    */
    public $forceGlobalSecureRequests = false;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Variables
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | 'sessionDriver'
    |
    |   The storage driver to use: files, database, redis, memcached
    |       - CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\FileHandler
    |       - CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\DatabaseHandler
    |       - CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\MemcachedHandler
    |       - CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\RedisHandler
    |
    | 'sessionCookieName'
    |
    |   The session cookie name, must contain only [0-9a-z_-] characters
    |
    | 'sessionExpiration'
    |
    |   The number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
    |   Setting to 0 (zero) means expire when the browser is closed.
    |
    | 'sessionSavePath'
    |
    |   The location to save sessions to, driver dependent.
    |
    |   For the 'files' driver, it's a path to a writable directory.
    |   WARNING: Only absolute paths are supported!
    |
    |   For the 'database' driver, it's a table name.
    |   Please read up the manual for the format with other session drivers.
    |
    |   IMPORTANT: You are REQUIRED to set a valid save path!
    |
    | 'sessionMatchIP'
    |
    |   Whether to match the user's IP address when reading the session data.
    |
    |   WARNING: If you're using the database driver, don't forget to update
    |            your session table's PRIMARY KEY when changing this setting.
    |
    | 'sessionTimeToUpdate'
    |
    |   How many seconds between CI regenerating the session ID.
    |
    | 'sessionRegenerateDestroy'
    |
    |   Whether to destroy session data associated with the old session ID
    |   when auto-regenerating the session ID. When set to FALSE, the data
    |   will be later deleted by the garbage collector.
    |
    | Other session cookie settings are shared with the rest of the application,
    | except for 'cookie_prefix' and 'cookie_httponly', which are ignored here.
    |
    */
    public $sessionDriver            = 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\FileHandler';
    public $sessionCookieName        = 'ci_session';
    public $sessionExpiration        = 7200;
    public $sessionSavePath          = WRITEPATH . 'session';
    public $sessionMatchIP           = false;
    public $sessionTimeToUpdate      = 300;
    public $sessionRegenerateDestroy = false;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cookie Related Variables
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | 'cookiePrefix'   = Set a cookie name prefix if you need to avoid collisions
    | 'cookieDomain'   = Set to .your-domain.com for site-wide cookies
    | 'cookiePath'     = Typically will be a forward slash
    | 'cookieSecure'   = Cookie will only be set if a secure HTTPS connection exists.
    | 'cookieHTTPOnly' = Cookie will only be accessible via HTTP(S) (no javascript)
    |
    | Note: These settings (with the exception of 'cookie_prefix' and
    |       'cookie_httponly') will also affect sessions.
    |
    */
    public $cookiePrefix   = '';
    public $cookieDomain   = '';
    public $cookiePath     = '/';
    public $cookieSecure   = false;
    public $cookieHTTPOnly = false;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Reverse Proxy IPs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your server is behind a reverse proxy, you must whitelist the proxy
    | IP addresses from which CodeIgniter should trust headers such as
    | HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and HTTP_CLIENT_IP in order to properly identify
    | the visitor's IP address.
    |
    | You can use both an array or a comma-separated list of proxy addresses,
    | as well as specifying whole subnets. Here are a few examples:
    |
    | Comma-separated:  '10.0.1.200,192.168.5.0/24'
    | Array:        array('10.0.1.200', '192.168.5.0/24')
    */
    public $proxyIPs = '';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross Site Request Forgery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Enables a CSRF cookie token to be set. When set to TRUE, token will be
    | checked on a submitted form. If you are accepting user data, it is strongly
    | recommended CSRF protection be enabled.
    |
    | CSRFTokenName   = The token name
    | CSRFCookieName  = The cookie name
    | CSRFExpire      = The number in seconds the token should expire.
    | CSRFRegenerate  = Regenerate token on every submission
    | CSRFRedirect    = Redirect to previous page with error on failure
    */
    public $CSRFTokenName  = 'csrf_test_name';
    public $CSRFCookieName = 'csrf_cookie_name';
    public $CSRFExpire     = 7200;
    public $CSRFRegenerate = true;
    public $CSRFRedirect   = true;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Content Security Policy
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Enables the Response's Content Secure Policy to restrict the sources that
    | can be used for images, scripts, CSS files, audio, video, etc. If enabled,
    | the Response object will populate default values for the policy from the
    | ContentSecurityPolicy.php file. Controllers can always add to those
    | restrictions at run time.
    |
    | For a better understanding of CSP, see these documents:
    |   - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/
    |   - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/
    */
    public $CSPEnabled = false;

}
```

when going to http://sub.domain.com, i am getting the default controller and view rendering.
However the CSS assets and JS assets that are linked:
https://sub.domain.com/assets/css/style.bundle.css

are all going to a server error.
the location of these files are actually in https://sub.domain.com/public/assets/css/style.bundle.css

but I am trying to avoid using /public/ in the url.

Any help or direction is appreciated.

RD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should have all your folders at the same level as root. This is assuming that /root is the publically accessible directory.

In other words,

```
/admin
/app
/root
   .htaccess
   favicon.ico
   index.php
   robots.txt
   /assets
/system
/vendor
/writable
```

Note that there is no directory named "public". Actually it's used to be called public, but it has been renamed "root". There is no requirement that it be named *public*, only that it is the directory your domain name points to.

You should be able to use all files as-distributed except for setting some things in app\config

Comment: Thank you, something so simple. I just removed the public folder and moved all the public files to the root. Modified the app location in the index.php. Resolved the issue.

Comment: it is safe to remove public folder?

Comment: You can remove public as long as the index.php file that CI provides is used in your webroot.